# Problem on finding Intersection form of compact,orientable $4-$manifolds .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, bilinear-form

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $M$ be an $\mathbb{F}$-oriented manifold of dimension $2 n$ for a field $\mathbb{F}$. Consider the non-singular bilinear form $H^{n}(M ; \mathbb{F}) \otimes H^{n}(M ; \mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ given by
$$
\langle\alpha, \beta\rangle=\langle\alpha \cup \beta,[M]\rangle .
$$
a) Prove that this form is symmetric if $n$ is even, and skew symmetric if $n$ is odd.

b) Classify all symmetric non-degenerate bilinear forms (up to isomorphism) on a $\mathbb{Z} / 2$-vector space $V$ of dimension $\leq 2$.

Find oriented 4-manifolds such that the underlying form is the given one in each case for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z} / 2$.

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ If $\operatorname{dim}(V)=1$, then a symmetric, bi-linear form is given by $\langle a, b\rangle=(a+b)\langle e, 0\rangle$ where $\langle e\rangle=V$,
So, a non-trivial bi-linear form is $\langle a, b\rangle=a+b$ and it's non - degenerate.

If $\operatorname{dim}(V)=2$, then if the bi-linear form is given by $\langle(a, b),(c, d)\rangle=ac+bd$ is symmetric and non-degenerate .

I found in a book that upto isometry, this is the only possible symmetric non-degererate, bi-linear form if $dim(V)=2.$

Take $S^{4}$ then $H^{2}\left(S^{4} ; \mathbb{Z}_{2}\right)=0$ hence $\alpha \cup \beta=0 \in H^{4}\left(S^{4} ; \mathbb{Z}_{2}\right)$.

Take $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$, then if $\alpha$ generates $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{2})$ implies $\alpha^{2}$ generates $H^{4}\left(\mathbb{CP}^{2}\right)$
$\therefore H^{2}\left(\mathbb {CP}^{2};\mathbb Z_{2}\right) \otimes H^{2}\left(\mathbb{C P} ; \mathbb{Z}_{2}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
is given by
$\langle {\alpha}^{2}, [\mathbb {CP}^{2}]\rangle=1$ as ${\alpha}^{2}$ is dual of $[\mathbb {CP^2}].$

I can't find any other compact,orientable $4-$ manifolds .
A help is much needed,thanks in advance .

Comment: What about $S^2\times S^2$? The square of any element in $H^2$ is trivial, and $\alpha\smile\beta$ generates $H^4$, where $\alpha,\beta$ generate $H^2$.

Comment: Yes, it's correct .